# Linux doesn't like my PC?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, mate, cinnamon

System Specs (Desktop PC):

- Intel Core i5 4460 (IGP enabled)
- Gigabyte H97-HD3 Motherboard
- 8gb DDR3 - 1600 Kingston RAM (4GB X2)
- Sapphire Radeon R9 380X GPU
- Currently main OS is Windows 10

Distros i tried:

- Kubuntu 18.10
- Linux Mint Mate and Cinnamon 19.1
- Linux Mint KDE 18.3
- Manjaro Linux KDE 18.04

**Using Sandisk 8 GB USB stick. Using lastest Rufus to prepare USB. No faults here because my laptop has no problem booting and installing from this. Currently running Kubuntu on my laptop with no issues at all.**

First of all, i searched these and some other forums elsewhere in hopes to finding a solution to my problem but i caould not find.

For starters, none of these distros can boot normally (with hardware acceleration). I can only see the grub menu or boot menu, can select to boot to corresponding OS and the screen goes "no-signal mode" for normal boot attempts. I have to boot with nomodeset option. Manjaro KDE does not boot at all.

For Kubuntu distro, i can boot to the screen where it asks if i want to try or install the OS. If i select the trial i see the messages in the screen shot.

I'd like to use Kubuntu mostly, because i like KDE desktop the most.

What is the problem? Is it my Radeon GPU? Not compatible with Linux kernel? Is there any way to install and run Kubuntu **with hardware acceleration**?

Please ask me if you need any detail.

[Screen after attempting to "try" Kubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTk4i.jpg)

Comment: You attempting to  dual boot your system. Are you installing both windows-10 and Linux on the same hard disk? My suggestion is you put off `hardware acceleration`  and see your dual boot is working fine! After confirming this you can bring `hardware acceleration` into picture. Also refer this link: https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-hardware-acceleration-and-why-it-matters/

Comment: No I'm not trying anything. The linux distros i mentioned don't boot normally in my system and i am trying to understand what the culprit is. I can't boot to Live USB session.

Comment: Does your desktop have  windows-10 installation?

Comment: Yes I'm running Windows 10 at the moment and my PC runs fine with it but i'd like to switch to a stable KDE Linux distro and be a part of this community

Comment: But first i'd like to try and see how Kubuntu runs on my system. But i can not boot into the Live environment to try it even under "nomodeset" mode

Comment: Check that your motherboard BIOS is current. See https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-H97-HD3-rev-10#support-dl-bios. Did you try the `irqpoll` kernel parameter? Report back.

Comment: My suggestion is that you concentrate on installing `KDE Linux distro` as you preferred. You can use [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Hardware-Acceleration) to turn off `hardware Acceleration` first. You have already with you `bootable` Sandisk 8 GB USB stick ready. You set up the top priority for USB stick in BIOS setup screen and complete KDE linux installation. Later thinks about enabling `hardware Acceleration` because you have `Radeon R9 380X GPU`.

Comment: irqpoll option is already present in "compatibility mode" and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your video card.

I've run Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.04-hwe just fine with an AMD Radeon HD 6950, and with an AMD Vega 64 video card, both with hardware acceleration.  All of these use the same family of drivers.  I also run some KDE applications in this environment, and they run fine.

The issue is probably how you are attempting to enable hardware acceleration, and/or if you are attempting to use the proprietary drivers.  Those proprietary AMD drivers are very finicky and only work with Linux kernel version up to 4.15.  Unless you have a reason not to, you should be using the open source mesa drivers (radeon, amdgpu, etc.)

Search for how to enable the latest versions of these, usually from adding the padoka ppa and adding a few lines to a xorg configuration file.

Comment: I am not trying to enable hardware acceleration. Currently i don't have any Linux distro installed. I can't boot to live USB session to try and see how Kubuntu runs on my system. What's preventing my system to boot to live session?

Comment: What do your grub lines look like (the ones where you put nomodeset)?

Comment: For Kubuntu i choose "nomodeset" option from its legacy mode boot menu, there are other options too but i don't want to tamper with something i don't know

Comment: Does the regular option not work?  In grub, go to a regular option, and press "e" to see the full lines.  Do the same for the nomodeset.  These lines tell grub what to actually boot (like where the "kernel" is, and which options to enable).

Comment: Regular boot doesn't work and compatible mode (nomodeset) does not work either. Havent tried the installtion yet because i want to see how/if Kubuntu works with my pc.